# regex help to end match on first occurent of a character

Tags: regex, sed

I have a following string in a configuration file:

```
path: (node) =>  `/${node.locale === 'en-US' ? 'en' : 'zh'}/${node.slug}`
```

I need to replace a fragment with a blank in some scenarios. The replacement will be done using `sed` on Linux just before build is triggered. Fragment to be replace is from the start of the `/` to the first `}`

`/${node.locale === 'en-US' ? 'en' : 'zh'}`

Unfortunately, I can get it to match the entire string all the way to the second `}`, but cant figure out how to make it stop.

Here is my sed command:

`sed 's/\/\${node\.locale.*?}/hello/' gridsome.config.js`

If I remove `?` it does work, but catches the entire line which won't work for this scenario.

Comment: In your case, something like `sed 's|/[^}]*}||'`

Comment: @BenjaminW. that worked!